# How do I ECHO a get_avatar from a PHP Email String

Tags: php, wordpress, email, echo, avatar

I'm new to PHP, How do I extract the email value from this string to get or  echo the user's avatar by email.

I've tried this and it does not seem to work.. by means of it not working, it displays the email and the default avatar which i want the script to use the email to get the avatar.

```html
<?php 
    $email = Sabai::_h($entity->getAuthor()->email);
    echo get_avatar( $email, 32 ); 
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is  $email  value?

Comment: this string extracts the authors email, I dont want to display the email I want to place that email in the echo so the avatar will display

Comment: But does it actually extract the author's email? Have you tried to `echo $email`?

Comment: Did I answer your question correctly @DeepKakkar? -- I'm sort of new to this.

Comment: @rnevius asked a question.. see

Comment: yes with the code above it displays the email and a default avatar not the users avatar.. I ONLY  want to display the users avatar from that string, am I making sense?

Comment: try var_dump($email) , if it shows an avatar image src , then use it

Comment: how would I rewrite that, Im learning.

Comment: @BhawinParkeria.. How would I rewrite this code so that the var_dump($smail) will work, Im clueless

Comment: just below the $email variable on line 1  try  var_dump($email); die;

Comment: that did not work, the output was the email address with null aside it with a no-image avatar...@BhawinParkeria

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace all of that with simple WordPress functions?

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?>
```

Comment: I've tried that but it does'nt work it only displays a default avatar

Comment: it does not display the users avatar so I found a string that displays the users email I want, now i want to get_avatar by email.

Comment: does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In actual The `get_avatar()` function applies a `get_avatar` filter hook in Wordpress

```
return apply_filters('get_avatar', $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt);
```

I think this would be the correct way to hook into this filter:

```
 function mytheme_get_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size ) {
  $avatar = '<img src="<' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/authors/' . $id_or_email . '.jpg" alt="' . get_the_author() . '" width="' . $size . 'px" height="' . $size . 'px" />';
   return $avatar;
 }
 add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'mytheme_get_avatar', 10, 32 );
```

So you can also go this way to resolve your issue. Good Luck!

Comment: dumb and break this down so that I (a baby in the industry) can understand. because it makes no sense.-- do I add this code in the function of my theme.. next what do I put in the single.php?

Comment: FYI check the link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22728/alternative-to-using-get-avatar-function

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are return object or array in `$email` variable or may be it is empty.
make sure you are getting correct email address so it will show `avatar` image if account is sign up on **[`Gravatar`](https://en.gravatar.com/)** else it will show up with `no-image`.

Try to output the variable **$email** right after the

```
$email = Sabai::_h($entity->getAuthor()->email);
var_dump($email); // To check it is array or object. 

echo get_avatar( $email, 32 );
```

Comment: that did not work, the output was the email address next to a no-image avatar

Comment: if i use $email = 'anyemailaddress'; it is working correctly.